# Restoring Cloudberry Bare Metal Backup to Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, backup, hyper-v, restore, bare-metal

I have a dead laptop from which I have a CloudBerry Bare Metal backup. I want to restore the image to a virtual machine. I used these instructions:

http://www.cloudberrylab.com/blog/how-to-perform-physical-to-virtual-restores-with-cloudberry-backup/

I have tried with both VirtualBox and Hyper-V. Both times the VM boots to a black screen with a old DOS-style cursor blinking.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. It appears there was a problem with the Master Boot Record (MBR). This article outlined the steps:

[Technet Article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/jonjor/archive/2011/10/04/vm-does-not-boot-following-p2v-or-disk2vhd.aspx)

I only needed to go to step 7.